# Identify deleted records in PDMlink by querying tables

Tags: ptc-windchill

The PDmlink records are hard deleted in WIndchill from the backend tables.

Users have access to delete the objects created and hence i need to find a way to identify the records deleted.

Is there any table which gives this information in PDMlink database?

Regards
Maha

Answer (score 0):

There is a table called `AUDITRECORD` in DB which has the details about all the events happened it includes Delete event. But the information will be available only if you have configured **Audit Event Recording**.
If you have configured then you can get the details by using below query.

```
select * from auditrecord where eventlabel='Delete';
```

Refer Windchill helpcenter for steps to configure audit event recording.

In case you have not done this configuration and still wants to fetch the data about deleted objects then

> Apache Web server logs and looking at backup of database or current
>   database doing a negation query to match part object identifer in
>   apache logs against those still remaining in database. Lot more work,
>   but not impossible.